# Prevent quit or disable back button android while running Unity 3D application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I would like to know how can I disable android back button or, at least, how to prevent app of quitting in case of accidental touch on this specific button, but I need the solution for **Unity 3D**. Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape) doesn't work :S I really need your help!

( Yes, I tried google... Thousands of times :) )

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: KeyCode.Escape is the way to go, I use it and it works fine. So I think there must be something in the way you're doing it that's wrong and we'd need more info on what you've tried in order to be able to help.

Comment: For example, if I put "if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){ Application.Quit(); }" in an active Update() function, my app quits when I press the back button. Are you sure you've got it in a function that's being called every frame?

Comment: Yes @Rupe, you're right. I had an "hidden" Application.Quit "lost" in a class to manage buttons, which made me fell a little bit dumb when I figured it out :( Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is to my understanding that you (or somebody else) have already implemented that functionality, because it won't work that way by default.

You can just search in your solution for "Application.Quit" or write the same method somewhere in your code then search for all references to the "Quit" method.

You will then be able to see where you have that functionality written and just delete the code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had an Application.Quit in the middle of a class for managing buttons. My bad! Thank you. I ticked your answer as the correct one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would prevent the back button from doing anything.  Not quite certain if this is the answer you are looking for because I don't know anything about Unity 3D.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// Leave blank if you do not want anything to happen
}
```

Comment: This is the override for native java/android application. I'm looking for a code snipet in C#/Unity3D. But thank you for your effort ;)

Comment: I figured it was.  Good luck!